# Card.io or Jumio phonegap/cordova plugin for Android

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, card.io

I need to implement either Card.io or Jumio in my phonegap/cordova application. I am aware that a card.io phonegap plugin exists for Iphone, but I need to get (or implement) it for the Android SDK. Can someone point me in the right direction / article? Any help on how to go about it would be great.

Comment: I'm not sure if you know this, or how it could work with phonegap, but there is also an Android library.

Comment: @dennisdrew thanks for the swift comment. I cant locate an existing Android library... Please can you point me towards it?

Comment: https://www.card.io/integrate/android

Comment: @dennisdrew I meant a phonegap/cordova wrapper around the Android SDK..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

card.io doesn't currently provide or maintain an Android Phone Gap plugin. To create one, you'd want to grab the [card.io Android SDK](https://www.card.io/integrate/android) and look at the [Phone Gap wiki instructions for creating Android plugins](http://phonegap.pbworks.com/w/page/36753494/How%20to%20Create%20a%20PhoneGap%20Plugin%20for%20Android). If you do create a plugin, please do contribute it back to Phone Gap repository!

Comment: For now, I figured out how to invoke the Card IO Activity from phonegap . However, I am now getting the message 'This device cannot use the camera to read card numbers' in both the emulator and while running an APK in my phone. The manifest file has the required camera permissions as well as recommended features such as autofocus, etc. Testing apk on a Nexus S running Jelly Bean.

Comment: Messages on LogCat : Failed to load Native Library : Library CardioDecider not found. - Processor Type is not supported. - cardioScanErrorNoDeviceSupport: This device cannot use the camera to read card numbers.    Well, even the Emulator emulates ARMv7 right?

Comment: @cosmicnag just to double-check: Are the native/compiled libraries from card.io in your project's "libs" subdirectory? (Cf. step 1.1 of https://www.card.io/integrate/android)

Comment: Yup thanks that was the problem. Now it does work on my phone, however it requires a lot of patience to get a card scanned correctly...

Comment: So any source?  I need to do the same thing, would be nice if you could share, lol.

Comment: still no card.io cordova android plugin??

Answer (score 2):

This is how I did it to make Card.IO work with phonegap ... I am sure its not the best way / the 'plugin' way...but if you want to quickly check out card.io with your app...

```
public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {

private CardIO cardIO;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.init();
    appView.addJavascriptInterface(cardIO, "cardIO");
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
}

}
```

In the above code, CardIO is a helper class which calls the CardIOActivity the usual way. It has a helper method for calling cardIO getCardDetails() (Sorry, I just lost the source for this..:( but it was nothing new/great actually..just a method calling cardioactivity and returning a string)

Now you can call it from your javascript interface like this :

```
console.log(window.cardIO.getDetails());
```

I would also like to point out that after trying this out, I found it quite difficult to scan a couple of (indian) credit cards I tried.. so as of now, I am not going to use card.io... will wait till it suits my needs properly...

Comment: Thanks, this should help get us going, quick and dirty works for me.

Answer (score 1):

We have developed an android plugin for card.io
Plugin can be downloaded from,

[Cubet Techno lab's phonegap plugins git repository](https://github.com/cubettech/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/card.io)

You need to integrate card.io android SDK first.  [Card io Android SDK](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-Android-SDK)

Enjoy :)

Comment: I tried to enable manual entry for this. A button shows up but the app crashes on clicking it .

Comment: @825K I am sorry, it was working long time ago, and I am not maintaining it anymore. Phonegap changed a lot in the meantime

Answer (score 0):

You can try this plugin 
[Card.IO for android](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/com.keepe.cardio)

Comment: App is crashing after adding this plugin ?